# I want to make the bot create a category and a text or voice chat in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def new_voice(ctx, name):
    await ctx.guild.create_voice_channel(name, *, category)
```

I'm still new to programming do not judge strictly and please fully explain what my error was I will be very grateful.

Comment: Can you include the full error? Also you should try `manage_channels=True` not administrator because manage channels also has permission to create new channels

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you create a new category and a channel inside of it:

```py
@client.command() # no need for pass_context, as it's passed automatically in rewrite
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True) # base permission for channel creation
async def newcategory(ctx, *, name):
    category = await ctx.guild.create_category(name)
    await category.create_voice_channel(f"{ctx.author.name}'s VC!")
```

Or you can check if a certain category already exists:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def newchannel(ctx, *, name):
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name="Category name!")
    if category: # checks if category exists (returns None otherwise)
        await category.create_voice_channel(name)
    else:
        category = await ctx.guild.create_category("Category name!")
        await category.create_voice_channel(name)
```

`*` means "consume rest", which allows you to have an argument with spaces in it (keep in mind that this can only be the last argument of a command, but you can have arguments before it)

---

**References:**

- [`Guild.create_category()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_category)
- [`CategoryChannel.create_voice_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.create_voice_channel)
- [`CategoryChannel.create_text_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.create_text_channel)
- [`utils.get()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get)
- [`Guild.categories`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.categories)